# Replicate a lookup table in all DWU in Azure Datawarehouse

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, data-warehouse, azure-synapse

I am using Azure Data Warehouse, I am pretty new to it. I have 60 DWU in my cluster. I want to create a lookup table that has just 10 rows in it and want it to be replicated or available in all the 60 DataWarehouse Units but not just one.
How do I achieve that ?

```
CREATE TABLE [src].[lkpTbl](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](100) NOT NULL
) 
WITH (DISTRIBUTION = REPLICATE);
GO
```

The above code isn't working , it fails with the error : `Option 'REPLICATE' is not supported in this version of SQL Server.`

Answer (score 2):

Azure SQL Data Warehouse does not support Replicated table currently. The only options available are HASH (column name) or ROUND_ROBIN. In this case since it's a small table use ROUND_ROBIN.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately ADW, because of how the Azure Data Centers provision resources it makes it architecturally difficult to offer REPLICATE tables. It is something that is being evaluated for potential inclusion in upcoming releases.

All the current table distribution methods (ROUND_ROBIN and HASH) spread the data across all 60 storage containers, the problem is when you use a distributed table as a lookup, there will be a Data Movement job that will be executed to use the data in the query.

In the example above if you are joining on the [ID] column you should use the following : 
WITH (DISTRIBUTION = HASH([ID]));

However if the table you are joining on is not distributed on that same joining table you will get a Data Movement job when the query executes. Alternatively if the lookup only has 1 column [Description], for performance I would say rather just denormalize the fact table and bring the description into the FACT table and leave the join on ID.